# Check radio button only if and when a dropdown list element is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery to check a radio button on page load:

```
$('input[value="modelos"]').attr('checked',true);
```

And then I have a dropdown list:

```
<select id="talents_meta_category" name="talents_meta_category">
<option value="tab_1495127126289">Modelos</option>
<option value="tab_1495132259463">Música</option>
</select>
```

How can I have `input[value="modelos"]` checked only if and when `<option value="tab_1495127126289">Modelos</option>` is selected?

Comment: you can use if condition to do so.

Comment: Apply condition statement such as;  IF this do this......, ELSE do otherwise.... This ensures that the condition is checked before the code is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need on change condition with if like this :

```js
$("select#talents_meta_category").change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() === "tab_1495127126289") {
    $('input[value="modelos"]').attr('checked',true);
  }else{
     $('input[value="modelos"]').attr('checked',false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="talents_meta_category" name="talents_meta_category">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="tab_1495127126289">Modelos</option>
<option value="tab_1495132259463">Música</option>
</select>

</br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="modelos 1" value="modelos"> modelos 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="modelos 2" value="modelos"> modelos 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="modelos 3" value="modelos"> modelos 3<br>
```

Checkbox dynamically change based on condition (select option value)

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether a option by testing the value attribute of the select

```js
  $(function(){
    if($('#talents_meta_category').val()){
      $('input[name="favorites"][value="modelos2"]').attr('checked',true);
}    
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="talents_meta_category" name="talents_meta_category">
  <option value=""></option>
<option value="tab_1495127126289">Modelos</option>
<option value="tab_1495132259463" selected>Música</option>
</select>
<label for="modelos"><input type="radio" name="favorites" value="modelos"></label>
<label for="modelos"><input type="radio" name="favorites" value="modelos2"></label>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, but I had to put in a blank option into the menu, however if that's unacceptable let me know and I'll do something else.

```js
$("select#talents_meta_category").change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() === "tab_1495127126289") {
    $('input[value="modelos"]').attr('checked',true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="talents_meta_category" name="talents_meta_category">
<option></option>
<option value="tab_1495127126289">Modelos</option>
<option value="tab_1495132259463">Música</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" value="modelos">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use onchange function.

```
  $("#talents_meta_category").on('change',function(){
           let value = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
          if(value=="tab_1495127126289"){
              $('input[value="modelos"]').attr('checked',true);
          }else{
       $('input[value="modelos"]').attr('checked',false);
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
// Your check the radio on page load
$('input[value="modelos"]').attr('checked', true);

// Check if `modelos` is selected
if ($('input[value="modelos"]').prop('checked')) {
  // Add the `selected` attribute to the <option />
  $('option[value="tab_1495127126289"]').attr('selected', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' value='modelos' />
<select id="talents_meta_category" name="talents_meta_category">
<option value="tab_1495127126289">Modelos</option>
<option value="tab_1495132259463">Música</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

You can do it many different ways, here is just one....

```
var checkMe = 'tab_1495127126289';

$(function(){
    $('input[name=talents_meta_category][value=' + checkMe + ']').prop('checked',true)
});
```